# How do machine learning applications communicate with one another?

Tags: machine-learning, api

My understanding is that if a company creates a machine learning application, they use an API to ensure that applications talk to one another, which is what I found in my initial research (https://www.ibm.com/cloud/learn/api). However, is this correct - is there an inner working within the machine learning application that enable two algorithms to connect? And how does this work in practice?

Comment: What do you mean with communicate? Is this a trained model that is in production and scoring? Is this during training? What is the communication supposed to do? What problem is trying to be solved?

Comment: What I mean is if an organisation is deploying many machine learning applications, how do they integrate them so they can talk to each other?

Comment: When do they communicate and what are they communicating? What is the purpose of the communication? For example, if during production, then when one model scores whatever it is they are scoring, the code that calls this model can send the score into a database, stream, API, to something else. That something else could be another model that scoring and uses the score from the first model as a feature.

Comment: I agree with Craig, the question is a bit unclear. In general two learning algorithms don't have any reason or ability to communicate with each other. An API is used mostly to feed the algorithm some input and receive the output, or set some parameters.